# C# split the string by white-spaces and remove the comma

Tags: c#

I have the string as: `बिहिबार, साउन ९, २०७६`

I wanted to separate the each character into a array, removing `,` and `spaces`

Output as:

```
बिहिबार
साउन
९
२०७६
```

I have tried to split the string first and remove the comma using the code:

`input.Split(@"\s+").Select(x => x.Replace(",", ""));`

However i have got the output as list of string as

[image]

Comment: `string.Split` doesn't take a regular expression.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: @Amy i have done the changes accordingly: `Regex.Split(dateSpan, @"\s+").Select(x => x.Replace(",", ""))`

Answer (score 3):

you can remove the commas and replace the spaces with newlines using the following:

```
string str = dateSpan.Replace(",","").Replace(" ", Environment.NewLine);
```

this does not create the array you were looking at, but does give the output you were looking for.

something closer to what you were doing is maybe:

```
var aStrs = 
    dateSpan.Split(" ,".ToCharArray(), System.StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToArray();
```

I know you said you want a char array, but it seems you want an array of strings.  If you want them as character arrays, just loop through them and do `.ToCharArray()`

Answer (score 2):

> I wanted to separate the each character into a array, removing , and spaces

Assume that this is actually what you want, and each of the connected symbols is it's own char, something like this should work:

```
string myst = "hi , this, is a, test";
char[] myar = myst.Replace(",", string.Empty).Replace(" ", string.Empty).ToCharArray();
```

If you want to split by spaces and commas (and not split each character to a `char` array):

```
string[] myar = myst.Split(new char [] {',' , ' '}).Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x)).ToArray();
```

Comment: why invoke `Where` when you can just use the built in option, `RemoveEmptyEntries`, as in: `dateSpan.Split(" ,".ToCharArray(), System.StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToArray();`

Comment: Just didn't think about that!

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, let's figure out the problem, then we can figure out how to fix it.

Let's break your expression out to make it easier to understand what's going on, firstly:

```
string[] split = input.Split(@"\s+"); // [0] = "बिहिबार, साउन ९, २०७६"
```

So, something is amiss before we even get to replacing the commas! Split is not correct, you are not splitting on a space like you think you are.

Let's just swap it out with a space (were you trying to use Regex there?):

```
var split = input.Split(" ")
    .Select(x => x.Replace(",", ""));
```

Et Voila! You have debugged your way to the result you expect.

**Edit:**
If we're discussing regex, you could do:

```
string[] split = Regex.Split(input, ",? +");
```

I believe you understand the how Regex and String split methods work, but by using this regex you can just straight up split your input string on '*an optional comma (**,?**) and then one or more spaces ( **+**)*'.

Comment: here in most cases i have only the similar string length, but generally in large context: what is the good choice. if i have to split with not just `comma` or `spaces`